# Melhorar resolução na escrita com Canvas HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

Como aumentar a resolução do traçado quando se desenha com Canvas no Dispositivo de Touch.
Posso aumentar a espessura do traço,  a cor do mesmo mas quando faço um círculo sai umas partes reto ou quadrado.

```js
var canvasWidth = 300;
var canvasHeight = 150;
var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('canvasDiv');
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.setAttribute('width', canvasWidth);
canvas.setAttribute('height', canvasHeight);
canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas');
canvasDiv.appendChild(canvas);
if (typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
  canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
}
context = canvas.getContext("2d");


$('#canvas').mousedown(function(e) {
  var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

  paint = true;
  addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
  redraw();
});

$('#canvas').mousemove(function(e) {
  if (paint) {
    addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
    redraw();
  }
});

$('#canvas').mouseup(function(e) {
  paint = false;
});

$('#canvas').mouseleave(function(e) {
  paint = false;
});

var clickX = new Array();
var clickY = new Array();
var clickDrag = new Array();
var paint;

function addClick(x, y, dragging) {
  clickX.push(x);
  clickY.push(y);
  clickDrag.push(dragging);
}

// Set up touch events for mobile, etc
canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
  mousePos = getTouchPos(canvas, e);
  var touch = e.touches[0];
  var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mousedown", {
    clientX: touch.clientX,
    clientY: touch.clientY
  });
  canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener("touchend", function(e) {
  var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mouseup", {});
  canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {
  var touch = e.touches[0];
  var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mousemove", {
    clientX: touch.clientX,
    clientY: touch.clientY
  });
  canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
}, false);

// Get the position of a touch relative to the canvas
function getTouchPos(canvasDom, touchEvent) {
  var rect = canvasDom.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: touchEvent.touches[0].clientX - rect.left,
    y: touchEvent.touches[0].clientY - rect.top
  };
}

// Prevent scrolling when touching the canvas
document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
  if (e.target == canvas) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);
document.body.addEventListener("touchend", function(e) {
  if (e.target == canvas) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);
document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {
  if (e.target == canvas) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);

function redraw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); // Clears the canvas

  context.strokeStyle = "#df4b26";
  context.lineJoin = "round";
  context.lineWidth = 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < clickX.length; i++) {
    context.beginPath();
    if (clickDrag[i] && i) {
      context.moveTo(clickX[i - 1], clickY[i - 1]);
    } else {
      context.moveTo(clickX[i] - 1, clickY[i]);
    }
    context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
    context.closePath();
    context.stroke();
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

#canvas {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvasDiv"></div>
```

Comment: pode postar um exemplo de código que está usando? comigo a resolução  nunca ficou tão ruim como você está dizendo.

Comment: Em que browsers você está tendo problema? E por favor poste um exemplo como pediu o Washington, para podermos todos testar o mesmo código.

Comment: @bfavaretto editei a pergunta com o codigo. lembrando que a resolução fica estranha quando em dispositivos touch

Comment: Para testes no mobile: http://output.jsbin.com/cozitihuha. No meu celular, funcionou razoavelmente bem.

Answer (score 1):

Não existe um comando para aumentar a resolução do canvas, um truque que você pode usar é desenhar o círculo em um canvas com o dobro do tamanho necessário e diminuir usando CSS, assim a resolução aumenta. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = 600;
canvas.height = 300;

ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,0,0)";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(300, 150, 100, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

```css
#canvas{
 width: 300px;
 height: 150px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```